# How to count the occurrences of the inner most arrays in a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a = np.array([
        [[1,1,1],[1,2,1], [1,1,1]],
        [[1,2,3],[1,1,1], [1,2,1]],
        [[1,2,1],[2,2,2], [1,2,1]],        
        ])
```

Given the above array, I want to obtain a dictionary below,

```
{(1,1,1): 3, (1,2,1): 4, (1,2,3): 1, (2,2,2): 1}
```

It is trivial to come up with a solution to loop through the array, check conditions, and store the 3-elment arrays and their counts in a dictionary. However, if the array `a` is large, for example 600 rows x 600 columns of 3-element components, the simple algorithm is unacceptably slow.
Could you suggest a better way? I am aware of `numpy.unique`, but it does not work with my situation.

Comment: Whatever you do will have to iterate over every element in the array to check it against your dictionary...  unless you build your dictionary at the same time you build your array. How are you populating this array?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny it is a typo.

Comment: @JeffUK if you meant how to construct such arrays, it is images converted into HSV color model.

Comment: How slow is 'unacceptably' slow? What speed would you consider acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy. First, your array is weirdly shaped. If you want to count rows, make it an array of rows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
        [[1,1,1],[1,2,1], [1,1,1]],
        [[1,2,3],[1,1,1], [1,2,1]],
        [[1,2,1],[2,2,2], [1,2,1]],        
        ])  # this is 3x3x3

a = a.reshape(9, 3)  # reshape into 2D
```

Then just count by `np.unique`:

```
vals, counts = np.unique(ax, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

Result:

```
vals: array([[1, 1, 1],
             [1, 2, 1],
             [1, 2, 3],
             [2, 2, 2]])

counts: array([3, 4, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Finally, the dict you wanted can be obtained as

```
{tuple(v): c for v, c in zip(vals, counts)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
              [[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]],
              [[1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1]],])
b = dict()
for i in list(a):
    for j in i:
        j = tuple(j)
        if j in b:
            b[j] += 1
        else:
            b[j] = 1
print(b)
```

Output:

```
{(1, 1, 1): 3, (1, 2, 1): 4, (1, 2, 3): 1, (2, 2, 2): 1}
```